# Getting error on running build-win32 in Cocos 2dx

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, cocos2d-x

I am newbie to Cocos 2dx trying to setup Cocos 2dx environment in Windows 7. I am using Visual Studio 2010 express edition.I am getting error "Solution file error MSB5009 : error parsing the nested project section in solution file" as given in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Assct.jpg) and [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bw9KiqSsETaEb3NxYWxMSFNKQlU/edit?usp=sharing) is the build result of the cocos2d-win32.vc2010 solution.I also tried changing the \MD \MT \MDd runtime libraries (Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Code Generation-> Runtime Library) one by one and then building the solution but still no success.

Thanks and Regards,
lazyandroid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out myself, Answer is before I was using Cocos 2dx 2.1.4 and Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2010, I downloaded Cocos 2dx rc0x-2.1.3 and Microsoft Visual studio Ultimate 2012 It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Open solution file (.sln) in visual studio and make a change in it (add new txt file and remove it from solution) and save the solution, Visual Studio will fix the problem in the solution file!